# What is the reason for this Valgrind error?

Tags: c++, string, valgrind

Valgrind is complaining with a substr invocation.

```
string Message::nextField(string& input) {
    int posSeparator = input.find_first_of(SEPARATOR);
    string temp;
    temp = input.substr(0, posSeparator); //Error points to this line
    input.erase(0, posSeparator + 1);
    return temp;
}
```

The error goes:
290 bytes in 12 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
What the function does is basically parse the input, returning portions of string separated by SEPARATOR character. This function is invoked from another class's method with the next definition:

```
void doSomething(string input) {
    input.erase(0,2);
    string temp = nextField(input);
    this->room = atoi(temp.c_str());
    temp = input;
    this->money = atoi(temp.c_str());
}
```

There's nothing else weird or important enough to be included here.
I use the default setup for Valgrind from Eclipse Indigo's Valgrind profiling.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you optimizing during compilation? If so, don't. This causes a lot of spurious reports from valgrind.

Comment: You could probably write `string temp = input.substr(0, posSeparator);` to initialize the string instead of assigning to it.  It is not obvious that is anything to do with your problem, though.

Comment: Does your program exit in a controlled fashion (e.g. by returning from main()) or does it just call exit() (or worse, _exit())?  I've found that if you want valgrind to be helpful regarding leaked memory, it's best to make sure your program exits by returning normally from main(), otherwise some things end up not getting freed up, which is fine from a practical standpoint (because the OS will free all the process's memory anyway) but valgrind sees it as leakage.

Comment: What is the input to the function?

Comment: You don't check if the posSeparator is actually different from string::npos - this might cause problems in the erase. It's a wild shot, but it might fix a bug anyway.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner main() exits normally.

Comment: @thiton Thanks, that was the problem. Answer it, or I will.

Comment: @Erandros Wow, didn't think that really was it, considering that string::npos == nlimits<uint>::max() quite often. Anyway, one can't argue with reality, and I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check if the posSeparator is actually different from string::npos - this might cause problems in the erase. It's a wild shot, but it might fix a bug anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not a bug in your code. This error could be reported due to details of implementation of C++ standard library. To verify this try the following from [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports):

> With GCC 2.91, 2.95, 3.0 and 3.1, compile all source using the STL
>   with -D__USE_MALLOC. Beware! This was removed from GCC starting with
>   version 3.3.
>
> With GCC 3.2.2 and later, you should export the environment variable
>   GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW before running your program.
>
> With GCC 3.4 and later, that variable has changed name to
>   GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an error somewhere else in your source. I tried to replicate the error using the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const char SEPARATOR = ':';

struct Foo
{
public:
    int room;
    int money;

    void doSomething(string input) {
        input.erase(0,2);
        string temp = nextField(input);
        this->room = atoi(temp.c_str());
        temp = input;
        this->money = atoi(temp.c_str());
    }

    string nextField(string& input) {
        int posSeparator = input.find_first_of(SEPARATOR);
        string temp;
        temp = input.substr(0, posSeparator); //Error points to this line
        input.erase(0, posSeparator + 1);
        return temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.doSomething("--234:12");
    std::cout << f.room << " - " << f.money << std::endl;
}
```

Then a ran valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck <executable>
```

and the output was:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 61 bytes allocated

All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

So, probably your problem is not in this part of code